# Rigid Body Physics with keyframed movements

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation

I'm creating a simple short video and have text that moves from one location to another and goes through a stack of blocks along the way. The text moves correctly but won't knock over the block as it should. The stack of blocks is 5x5 and stacked vertically. The blocks are dynamic and convex hulls and the text is dynamic and convex. I'm very confused as to why the physics aren't working. Any ideas?
Update: The problem has been solved. For some reason the blocks were checked as animated and I just didn't notice.

Comment: Text objects by default are bezier curves, and bezier curves can't for the most part be used in physics simulations directly, as far as I know. You mus convert (a copy of it) to a mesh object to be usable in rigid body simulations.

Comment: I have already converted the text into a mesh and solidified it and for some reason it just passes through still